# Check If Date Is Between Two Dates

Tags: objective-c

Good afternoon,

How do you check if a date is between two dates? I know I have to convert the data strings to NSDate values first:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/01/2001"];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/01/2010"];

NSDate *userDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/2001"];
```

And then I have to use an if-statement, but I am not quite sure how to go about it. Here is what I need:

> if (userDate is between date1 and date2)
>   {
>
> }

Any help with the if-statement would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `-compare:`:

```
if (([date1 compare:userDate] == NSOrderedAscending) && ([date2 compare:userDate] == NSOrderedDescending)) {
        // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

of the top of my head so check the syntax ;-)

```
if (([userDate laterDate: date1] == userDate) && ([userDate laterDate: date2] == date2)){
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quick! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(([userDate compare: date1] ==  NSOrderedDescending) && ([userDate compare: date2] == NSOrderedAscending)){
//do something
}
```